# ngspice MOSFET region of operation

Tags: mosfet, saturation, ngspice

how to find region of operation of MOSFET in a circuit in ngspice? or how do you know that a MOSFET is in saturation in a circuit in ngspice?

Comment: Study a textbook about the operation of the MOSFET. Then you will learn the conditions that will cause the MOSFET to operate in saturation or not. Then looking at the voltages and currents in your ngspice simulation you can determine if the MOSFET is in saturation or not.

Comment: Thank you. The condition is Vds > (Vgs - Vt), however, is it sufficient condition for spice models? as lambda and other parameters are considered in spice models

Comment: That is indeed the condition for saturation ! It has no relation to the spice models, I mean, why would it ? The spice model just models the transistor. All the parameters in the spice model combined with the currents and voltages you apply result in the transistor behaving in a certain way. Then you just evaluate Vds > (Vgs - Vt) end that tells you if the transistor is in saturation or not. Do note that for example Vt depends on the body effect so if that effect is present (Vsb > 0V) Vt increases and Vdssat gets a different value (compared to Vsb = 0 V).

Answer (score 1):

When Vds >> 4Ut, the devices is in saturation.  4Ut is approximately 100mV, and at that point, the Forward current dominates because the reverse current is <1%.  Read up in any semiconductor book.

The reason that I answered this is because the SPICE level depends on if this reverse current is modeled at all.  I have seen some SPICE 3.3 models not even include this effect.  How you should prove the effect is to hold the gate at 3.3V, hold the source at 0V and sweep the drain in steps of 10mV from 0V to 120mV in steps of 5mV.  The change in current through the devices will tell you if your model level includes the effect.  If the current is the same at 100mV as 0mV, your models are using the default values, that do not show the reverse current.

Comment: I have been working with MOSFETs for 25 years and this is the first time I see someone claiming saturation occurs at Vds >> 4 Ut. In my opinion either you misunderstood this or the semiconductor books you read are all wrong. But I'm open to new views on this topic so if you know better then please convince me that what you state is true.

Comment: I did a quick search and Dr. Minch does the derivation how I do it: http://madvlsi.olin.edu/circuits/handouts/160305_mosmodel.pdf, section 4.7 on page 13.  I'm more of a device physicist than an EE, so often it's just a matter of notation.  For text books, I use the work by Andy Grove or Carver Mead.   I derive my own EKV and SPS models because BSIM is particularly bad in subvt or Vds<100mV.

Comment: Yeah, OK, that's in the **weak inversion region**. I almost exclusively design circuits using MOSFETs in **strong inversion**. In the weak inversion region, MOSFETs are very slow, more noisy, have more **unreliable modelling** (you state this as well) and are almost unusable in general. The only use for a MOSFET in weak inversion is in ultra low power applications. So your statement that **Vds >> 4 Ut is correct** as long as you also state that this is in **weak inversion operation** ! Which is a region most circuit designers never use.

Comment: I disagree with your assertions across the board.  The Vds >> 4Ut   for weak vs. 5Ut for strong inversion best case; however, every practical device is about 4Ut due to higher order effects.  The physics of subthreshold is simple, and the models are excellent due to the simple physics, whereas above Vt is not.  A note on the models: the modeling issues that I see are usually due to BSIM and default values, which is why I specifically mentioned that in the original post.  All models should be swept across all quadrants just for sanity.  There's a lot of trust of models without asking the "why".